# Validation of user input while using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am having trouble using `Scanner` to take user input and store it in a variable. The problem is, when the user is entering the input the method is entering into an infinite loop.

i.e. The user is able to enter any value or spaces but the program doesn't take them as input and proceed to next step of assigning them to variable.

```
public class AS10 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double X = 0;
        double Y = 0;
        System.out.println("please enter the value of X-cordinate and Y cordinate :");
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scn.hasNext()){
         X = scn.nextDouble();
         Y = scn.nextDouble();
        }

        System.out.println("  the value of y is " + Y+ "the value of x is "+ X);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `while` loop. There is nothing that you have in your code that will cause the loop to end.

Just remove it and your code works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double X = 0;
    double Y = 0;
    System.out.println("please enter the value of X-cordinate and Y cordinate :");
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    X = scn.nextDouble();
    Y = scn.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("  the value of y is " + Y + " the value of x is " + X);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` class's `hasNext` method checks if there are available tokens in the input. You dont need a while loop for error handling. Surround the assignment statements (which gets the value from `nextDouble` method) in a try catch block and handle the exceptions accordingly.

Or you could use `hasNextDouble` method to check if there are available `double` values in the input.